# How can the prior distribution of bayes regression be estimated by empirical bayes?

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear-model, prior

Neither in Efron's book [Large-scale Inference:Empirical Bayes Methods for Estimation, Testing and Prediction](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/110761967X) nor by Internet search, did I find a prior distribution estimation method of Bayes regression from the perspective of empirical Bayes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the books

[An Introduction to Bayesian Inference in Econometrics by Zellner](https://amzn.to/2EeYUfb)

[Bayesian Econometrics by Gary Koop](https://amzn.to/2N8fbW1)

[The Oxford Handbook of Bayesian Econometrics by John Geweke, Gary Koop and Hermann van Dijk](https://amzn.to/2Iih0kn)

[Bayes and Empirical Bayes Methods for Data Analysis by Brad Carlin and Thomas Louis](https://amzn.to/2BCLCHN)

Comment: It's a pity that these excellent books have no Chinese version ಠ╭╮ಠ