# Bayesian hierarchical model on large data as a meta-analysis

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, meta-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I would like to fit a mixed effects model on a large dataset, and with a large number of parameters, which makes it computationally prohibitive.
As an alternative, I considered fitting (1) multiple group-level models (with flat priors), (2) approximating the posterior of each group-level model with a multivariate normal, and (3) fitting the hierarchical part to the approximations of group-level posteriors. In other words, the actual hierarchical model wouldn't use the data, but only estimates of group-level models.

The fact that so far I haven't read about this being done routinely makes me think that this might be a bad idea.
I'd appreciate either any explanations of why this is not a good idea, or any pointers to literature on this or a similar methodology.

Comment: What you've described as your "alternative" strategy sounds a lot like [Empirical Bayes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/392781).

Comment: How large is your dataset and parameter count?  A lot of problems that seem computationally prohibitive aren't, really...